# How to keep CMD open and run commands on it using python?

Tags: python, cmd, pip

I have to write a code for a group project and no one else knows anything about coding. I will have to make them install some libraries using pip for the code to learn which they might find pretty complicated. So i thought of writing a code for them which will install the libraries using the os module. But i dont know how to keep CMD open after it has installed since it closes as soon as the command is executed. PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: use bash script or bat script

Comment: So you have a python program that is exiting? Is it double-clicked from Windows? At the end you could just add `input("Press any key to terminate")` and it wlll stay up waiting for user input.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the thing is i want cmd to stay open not the python program. Like im using os.system().

Comment: It would help to include the operating system you are targetting and how the program is execute by the users.

Comment: How is "CMD" envolved? Are you writing something that calls cmd.exe? And why do that when you have a python program that can do whatever cmd.exe can do? Perhaps an example of your use of cmd.exe would help.

Comment: the program will be double clicked and operating sys is windows 10. For example: 
os.system('pip install pandas')

Comment: I don't have windows up at the moment. It may work to skip the intermediate shell. So, `import subprocess as subp` followed by `subp.run(["pip", "install", "pandas"])`. This should skip cmd.exe competely because the method defaults to `shell=False`.

Comment: Yes thank you so much this worked!! :)

Comment: More generally, if you install your scripts through the regular python setuptools / setup.py / pip path (its a good idea to do that), you can add these to `install_requires` and get pip to do it for you. Thats the standard way to deal with these dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a .bat file with a "Pause" at the end.

Comment: But a python `input` works as well. Python is generally considered a richer programming environment to .bat.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by moving away from running python in the command line. There are some great package managers like Anaconda which also have nice IDEs such as spyder or VS code which can help with writing code if you are not beyond the write in notepad run in cmd stage yet.

You can then use anaconda prompt for package management operations. May i suggest looking into "pip install -r requirements.txt" still needs some user input but  this is a great way of making sure someone has all the right packages. without them having to do pip install many times.

As for a direct solution to your problem, if you start cmd first, navigate to the directory via cmd and then from that terminal do "python file.py" you should be able to see output without the window closing. Though using an interactive IDE is  much better. I'm on linux at the moment so may have skipped something.

Comment: The thing is im not running the code on cmd. I use the official IDLE. but the pip commands i will have to run on cmd. So i run the code on idle and use the command:
os.system('pip install pandas')

Comment: So my first thought is you really need to look into Anacoda, the base install comes with most things like pandas and numpy so you may need nothing more if it's just base packages your using.

See if this video is what your looking for,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnpC_Ib_lbc